# Search form with ability to share the URL in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, url, parameters, use-state, history

I am trying to build a simple search component in ReactJs with the ability to write the search params in the URL, then the URL could be shared with someone, and the search could be started automatically if the input query (of the URL) is not empty.

At this state of my POC, the problem is when I type something in my input box, it is written automatically in the URL (because of useState I guess).
I would like to write the query in the URL only when I click the search button, but because of the hook I am unable to do this.

Here is my code :

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import history from "./history";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Search from './Search';


function App() {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={Search}/>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Search.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import history from "./history";


const Search = (props) => {

  let params = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
  let query = params.get("query") != null ? params.get("query"): "";

  const [search, setSearch] = useState(query);
    
  function startSearch() {
    history.push(`/?query=${search}`);

    console.log(`Result : ${search}`);
  }

  // Start search on the page if a query has been set
  if (query.length > 0) startSearch();

  return (
    <div>
        <input value={search} onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}/>
        <button onClick={startSearch} >Search</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of things you need to change to have this work.

1. Firstly, remove the line that says `if (query.length > 0) startSearch();`. This like is put in the wrong place. Where it is, it is executed on every render. Which means every time that component renders, it'll update the search query.
2. Secondly, The correct place to put that code is inside a `useEffect` hook, which will only call the function on the first render. So replace that line with:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (query.length > 0) startSearch();
}, [])
```

That should solve the issues you're facing. Let me know if you need any more help.